# Restart-computer command in start-job scriptblock always returns as state “blocked”

Tags: wpf, powershell, start-job

If I run the code below then the created job “test3” always has a state “blocked”. It never executes. It has no additional error message.
When I run the command in the start-job scriptblock separately, then it does work (restart-computer -computername $computer -credential $MySecureCreds -force).

```
[void] 
[xml]$XAML = @"

<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

    Title="CSS Server Reboot" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="Server_Combobox" SelectedValuePath="Content" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="120">
         <ComboBoxItem Name="Server1">10.15.12.148</ComboBoxItem>          
    </ComboBox>
    <Label Name="Title_Label" Content="CSS – Server Reboot&#xD;&#xA;" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,41,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Height="34" Width="284" FontSize="16"/>
    <Button Name="Reboot_Button" Content="Reboot" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="449,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <TextBox Name="Reboot_Textbox" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Height="173" Margin="81,180,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
Width="294"/>
</Grid>
</Window>

"@
#Read XAML
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
try{$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader"; exit}

# Store Form Objects In PowerShell
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {Set-Variable -Name 
($_.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}


# Secure credential creation
$Username = "XXX"
$Password = "XXX"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$SecureString = $pass
$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName 
System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass 

# Use the combobox
$computer
$jobtest
$timer = new-object System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer


$Server_Combobox.add_SelectionChanged( { 

param($sender, $args)

$Script:computer = $sender.SelectedItem.Content

} )



#Assign reboot event to button
$Reboot_Button.Add_Click({

$sb = [scriptblock]::Create("restart-computer -computername $computer -
 credential $MySecureCreds -force")
Start-Job -Name "test3" -ScriptBlock $sb 

$Script:jobtest = Get-Job -Name "test3"

$Reboot_Textbox.AddText("The restart procedure is starting.`n")

$timer.Interval = [TimeSpan]"0:0:5.00"


$timer.add_Tick({

if($jobtest.State -ne "Running"){
$Reboot_Textbox.AddText("The restart failed, please contact IT Ops !!!`n")
$Reboot_Textbox.AddText("The error message is:`n")
$Reboot_Textbox.AddText($jobtest.ChildJobs[0].JobStateInfo.State)
$Reboot_Textbox.AddText("`n")
$Reboot_Textbox.AddText($jobtest.ChildJobs[0].JobStateInfo)
$Reboot_Textbox.AddText("`n")
$Reboot_Textbox.AddText($jobtest.ChildJobs[0].Error)
$Script:timer.Stop()
}elseif($jobtest.State -eq "Completed"){
$Reboot_Textbox.AddText("The restart procedure completed successfully.")
$Script:timer.Stop()
Wait-Job -Name test3 | Remove-Job
}else{
$Reboot_Textbox.AddText("The restart procedure is ")
$Reboot_Textbox.AddText($jobtest.State)
$Reboot_Textbox.AddText("`n")
}         

})

$timer.Start()

})

$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? Does it have to do with the “credential” option in the scriptblock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create("restart-computer -computername $computer -credential $MySecureCreds -force")
```

To this:

```
$sb = { restart-computer -computername $Using:computer -credential $Using:MySecureCreds -force }
```

You need the `Using:` scope modifier so that the current value gets injected into the scriptblock.

When you do it the first way, using double-quoted strings, the variables get put inside the string before the scriptblock is created.

You end up with something like:

```
$sb = { restart-computer -computername WhateverIsInComputer -credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -force }
```

Which won't work.

Comment: The alternative is using single-quotes when passing to the `Create` method in this scenario.

Comment: These solutions don’t work. When I try the solutions I receive a state “failed” for the start-job with the error “Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.”
When I use the computer address in the command, instead of the variable $computer, I again receive a state “blocked” for the start-job with no error.

Comment: If I use a test-connection command in the scriptblock for the start-job then it does work:
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create("Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer")

Comment: @PeterSerdons you're right I left out an important part about the `Using:` scope modifier, which I've edited into the answer.